# Handling multiple basepath in swagger

Tags: java, rest, web.xml, swagger, swagger-ui

I am using swagger-ui to provide nice documentation for REST APIs to our clients.
Internally we have two different environments jenkin builds the project to.
E.g. swagger.json is accessible on both environment as:
`http://www.myhost.com/xyz/rest/swagger.json
https://www.myhost2.com/rest/swagger.json`

Documentation is available as:
`http://www.myhost.com/xyz/dist/index.html
https://www.myhost2.com/dist/index.html`

swagger api basepath in web.xml is:

```
<init-param>       
     <param-name>swagger.api.basepath</param-name>
     <param-value>/rest</param-value>
</init-param>
```

ISSUE:
I am trying to use "Try it out" feature on documentation page.
The respective request url for both hosts are as follows:
`http://www.myhost.com/rest/getAUser
https://www.myhost2.com/rest/getAUser`

It works for host2 as it is hitting the correct url. However it should have hit `http://www.myhost.com/xyz/rest/getAUser` for host1 but it is hitting the url `http://www.myhost.com/rest/getAUser`.

Is there a way I can specify multiple basepath for different urls.

My swagger-ui html looks something like this.

```
$(function () {
var href = window.location.href;
var url = href.substring(0, href.lastIndexOf("/dist"));
console.log(url);
// Pre load translate...
if(window.SwaggerTranslator) {
window.SwaggerTranslator.translate();
}
window.swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({
url: url + "/rest/swagger.json",
dom_id: "swagger-ui-container",
......
......
}
```

Comment: Completely irrelevant to the question, but `/getAUser` is of course not proper REST design. GET is the operation and your url should consist of nouns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by configuring swagger using BeanConfig instead of using Servlet in web.xml

BeanConfig class:

```
public class SwaggerBootstrap extends DefaultJaxrsConfig {

    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = myAutoGeneratedID;

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {

        super.init(config);
        //contextPath will be null for host2 and /xyz for host1.
        String contextPath = config.getServletContext().getContextPath();

        BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
        beanConfig.setVersion("1.0.0");
        beanConfig.setTitle("My API Documentation");
        beanConfig.setSchemes(new String[] {
                "http", "https"
        });
        beanConfig
        .setResourcePackage("com.example.my.rest.api.package");

        beanConfig.setBasePath(contextPath + "/rest");
        beanConfig.setScan(true);
    }
}
```

and in web.xml:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>SwaggerBootstrap</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>my.package.to.SwaggerBootstrap</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <!-- This make sure that all resources are scanned whether or not they use Swagger Annotations. 
            https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-samples/tree/master/java/java-jaxrs-no-annotations -->
            <param-name>scan.all.resources</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

And I changed my pom.xml to start using latest stable version of swagger-jersey2-jaxrs:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
```